# Output works and get "undefined" value too

Tags: javascript, methods, include

I've this little code:

```
var mobili='mqihfdbacegklnprtuz&xyso';
function encrypt(index){
 if(mobili.includes(index)){
   var test = "It's working";
   console.log(test)
 }
 else{
   var test = "Bueller? Bueller?";
   console.log(test);
 }
}
console.log(encrypt('j'));
```

So... This code works but the output get to me the "undefined" value too. Why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MygqU.jpg)

PS: I'm in repl.it website to run this one.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, so the final console.log has nothing to output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function isn't `return`ing anything - it's actually calling `console.log` itself. You can fix this in two ways:

One: Add a `return` statement to your function instead of using `console.log`:

```
function encrypt(index){
 if(mobili.includes(index)){
   var test = "It's working";
 }
 else{
   var test = "Bueller? Bueller?";
 }
 return test;
}
```

Two: Call the function without using `console.log`:

```
encrypt('j');
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless explicitly mentioned a function always return an `undefined`. This function `encrypt` is not explicitly returning anything. It is just consoling the statement

You can return `test` from the function

```js
var mobili = 'mqihfdbacegklnprtuz&xyso';

function encrypt(index) {
  if (mobili.includes(index)) {
    return "It's working";
    
  } else {
    return "Bueller? Bueller?";
    
  }
}
console.log(encrypt('j'));
```

Comment: You don't need the `else` - if the condition is true, the function will cease to execute, but if it's false, it'll skip straight over the `if` and straight to the default procedure.